# jQuery positioning

Tags: jquery, hover

Click [Here](http://www.mbu.mn/test/)!
Just click on the Click this links. The slide's messed up.

I uploaded a picture.

Click [Here for image](http://www.mbu.mn/test/123.png)!

Comment: We have no idea what a perfectly working version of this would look like. What _specific_ problem are you having? What code segment do you suspect to be the culprit of said abnormality? What have you tried? Please... throw us a bone, we aren't your tech support.

Comment: What is the exact problem? is it that there's no button to hide it or what?

Comment: The slide going out of the frame! Isn't it obvious?

Comment: That is what's needed right?!?

Comment: @techfoobar which slide is going out of which frame?

Comment: Okey guys the problem is slide is going out of the frame. It has to slide from right to left. And it has to be dynamic so the screen resolution won't break the site.

Comment: Its animating to the left and out of the viewport. Checking in FF.

Comment: For me it is in my viewport...

Comment: Maybe you should change the plugin. Its URL is dead - http://srobbin.com/jquery-pageslide/ . Animating is straight forward, maybe you should roll your own. Or use another plugin.

Comment: @Mr.Alien - For me it starts out from the center of the viewport to the left and stops half way out of it. i.e. only half the slide is visible.

Comment: oh, that's why I was not able to make out what's the progblem, for me click this is completely in center and the modal window comes from left and flows to right, but all this is completely inside my viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
left: 100px;
```

to your `#pageslide` CSS.

Comment: ok it can solve the problem for only on my screen. but the other screen resolutions it will break. Can you make it dynamically?

Comment: No, it'll always be `100px` for all resolutions and view-port sizes. If you put in the close button in your second modal as well, you won't even need the duplicate close button on the left and can make `left: 0` so it'll always move right to the left of the browser window.

Comment: "No, it'll always be 100px" this is the prob :P. what i'm trying to say is left: dynamic or something like that. smaller resolution screen will will not gonna fully hover the main page.