# Different Browser problems, jQuery or css error

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, browser, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery positioning porblem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685327/jquery-positioning-porblem)

Okey guys if you see the link on FF 15 it's good.

http://www.mbu.mn/test/

and the other browsers it will break. Break means it's not overlaying the exact size. it goes more to the left so it looks bad. My english is very bad so please understand my problem :P

Please help on this one.

Ok the Html is like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Nofu Entertaiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.pageslide.css" />
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="javascript:$.pageslide.close()">Close</a></p>
<div id="main">

    <div id="content">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#modal" class="second">Click This ..</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#modal1" class="second">Click This ..</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="modal">
            <h2>Modal</h2>
                <p>This slide uses "modal" option set to "true". When using a modal pageslide, clicking on the main window will not close the window. You must explicitly call <code>$.pageslide.close()</code>.</p>
                <p><a href="javascript:$.pageslide.close()">Close</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="modal1">
            <h2>testing 1 2 3</h2>
            <p>test test <code>$.pageslide.close()</code>.</p>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.pageslide.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* Default pageslide, moves to the right */
        $(".first").pageslide();

        /* Slide to the left, and make it model (you'll have to call $.pageslide.close() to close) */
        $(".second").pageslide({ direction: "left", modal: true });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and The css is

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
#content {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #999999;
}
#content h1 {
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1em;
}
#content ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#content ul li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#modal {
    display: none;
}
#modal a {
    background: #CCC;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
}
#modal a:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}
#modal1 {
    display: none;
}
#modal1 a {
    background: #CCC;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
}
#modal1 a:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}
#pageslide {
    /* These styles MUST be included. Do not change. */
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    /* Specify the width of your pageslide here */
    width: 600px;
    /* These styles are optional, and describe how the pageslide will look */
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #222;
    -moz-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #222;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #222;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the jquery is

```
/*
 * jQuery pageSlide
 * Version 2.0
 * http://srobbin.com/jquery-pageslide/
 *
 * jQuery Javascript plugin which slides a webpage over to reveal an additional interaction pane.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Scott Robbin (srobbin.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*/
;(function(b){function j(e,a){if(0===e.indexOf("#"))b(e).clone(!0).appendTo(c.empty()).show();else{if(a){var d=b("<iframe />").attr({src:e,frameborder:0,hspace:0}).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});c.html(d)}else c.load(e);c.data("localEl",!1)}}function k(b,a){var d=c.outerWidth(!0),f={},g={};if(!c.is(":visible")&&!h){h=!0;switch(b){case "left":c.css({margin:"0 0 0 600px"});f["margin"]="0 auto"+d;g.right="+="+d;break;default:c.css({left:"-"+d+"px"}),f["margin"]="0 auto"+d,g.left="+="+d}l.animate(f,a);c.show().animate(g,a,function(){h=!1})}}var l=b("#main"),c=b("#pageslide"),h=!1,m;0==c.length&&(c=b("<div />").attr("id","pageslide").css("display","none").appendTo(b("#main")));b.fn.pageslide=function(e){this.click(function(a){var d=b(this),f=b.extend({href:d.attr("href")},e);a.preventDefault();a.stopPropagation();c.is(":visible")&&d[0]==m?b.pageslide.close():(b.pageslide(f),m=d[0])})};b.fn.pageslide.defaults={speed:500,direction:"right",modal:!1,iframe:!0,href:null};b.pageslide=function(e){var a=b.extend({},b.fn.pageslide.defaults,e);c.is(":visible")&&c.data("direction")!=a.direction?b.pageslide.close(function(){j(a.href,a.iframe);k(a.direction,a.speed)}):(j(a.href,a.iframe),c.is(":hidden")&&k(a.direction,a.speed));c.data(a)};b.pageslide.close=function(c){var a=b("#pageslide"),d=a.outerWidth(!0),f=a.data("speed"),g={},i={};if(!a.is(":hidden")&&!h){h=!0;switch(a.data("direction")){case "left":g["margin"]="0 auto"+d;i.right="-="+d;break;default:g["margin"]="0 auto"+d,i.left="-="+d}a.animate(i,f);l.animate(g,f,function(){a.hide();h=!1;"undefined"!=typeof c&&c()})}};c.click(function(b){b.stopPropagation()});b(document).bind("click keyup",function(e){"keyup"==e.type&&27!=e.keyCode||c.is(":visible")&&!c.data("modal")&&b.pageslide.close()})})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i really don't know the problem that causing the margin.

Comment: I tried it on FF and Chrome, it seems to work similarly. Please update your question with more details about what "breaks". Also, show the HTML and JavaScript you need help with.

Comment: okey the error is like a problem. i'm on FF 15 and the slide is overlaying the content fully. But on Chrome or Safari it goes more to the left. Not overlaying it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a CSS error, and its just a matter of margins or paddings.
Can you clean the css a bit so you dont get confused?

then I think for the float :left you made, you need to clear:both them first.

Comment: Sorry for my Bad english

Comment: Zdravstvuj (Hello). no problem. you're english seems ok.

Comment: So do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Its obviously the **CSS**

try to Use CSS framework on your projects...

http://speckyboy.com/2012/08/21/15-more-responsive-css-frameworks-boilerplates-worth-considering/